# Check if a specific role has read access to an item

Tags: security, permissions

Is there a way to check if a specific user role has been granted read permission to a specific item?

I've tried using `item.Security.CanRead(role)` but to no success (this returns `true` when I'd expect `false`).

Edit:

May have been a bit premature with this, I seem to be able to achieve it with;

```
foreach(var role in roles)
{
    var accessRules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();
    foreach (var accessRule in accessRules)
    {
        if (accessRule.Account == role && accessRule.AccessRight == Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRight.ItemRead)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

but any more succient methods would be good!

Answer (score 8):

The code you pasted above is incorrect. It doesn't check roles inheritance.

`item.Security.CanRead(role)` method is exactly what you're looking for.

If it returns you `true` when you expect it to return `false`, most probably you should check:

- `AccessViewer` application and see why that role has `read` access to the item
- role inheritance - maybe one of the base roles has `read` access granted
- check if your code is not used in `SecurityDisabler` context

Comment: Thank you for this, was pulling my hair out trying to grab roles that could read an item during indexing. I assume there is a `SecurityDisabler` context higher up the execution so I simple wrapped the `item.Security.CanRead(role)` in a `SecurityEnabler()` and that did the trick.